# Estimation Delivery date by admin

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I am searching for an extension admin can able to set the delivery date for the order.
The default order estimation date will be 2 days. If it delays means the admin can change the date of a delivery order in the backend for particular order.

Could Please Suggest Extension for this.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/ecomteck/module-delivery-date

Comment: https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date

Comment: But i think you should know how to search in google!

Comment: thank you @RonakChauhan